# Fastest way to sum over rows of sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a big csr_matrix(1M*1K) and I want to add over rows and obtain a new csr_matrix with the same number of columns but reduced number of rows. Actually my problem is exactly same as this [Sum over rows in scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629821/sum-over-rows-in-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix). The only thing is I find the accepted solution to be slow for my purpose. Let me state what I have

```
map_fn = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000000)
```

`map_fn` here tells me how my input rows(1M) are mapped into my output rows(10K). For example ith input row gets added up into `map_fn[i]`  output row. I tried the two approaches mentioned in the above question,
 namely forming a sparse matrix and using sparse sum. Although the sparse matrix approach looks way better than sparse sum approach but I find it slow for my purpose. Here is the code comparing two approaches:

```
import scipy.sparse
import numpy as np 
import time

print "Setting up input"
s=10000
n=1000000
d=1000
density=1.0/500

X=scipy.sparse.rand(n,d,density=density,format="csr")
map_fn=np.random.randint(0, s, n)

# Approach 1
start_time=time.time()
col = scipy.arange(n)
val = np.ones(n)
S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix( (val, (map_fn, col)), shape = (s,n))
print "Approach 1 Creation time : ",time.time()-start_time
SX = S.dot(X)
print "Approach 1 Total time : ",time.time()-start_time

#Approach 2
start_time=time.time()
SX = np.zeros((s,X.shape[1]))
for i in range(SX.shape[0]):
    SX[i,:] = X[np.where(map_fn==i)[0],:].sum(axis=0)

print "Approach 2 Total time : ",time.time()-start_time
```

which gives following numbers:

```
Approach 1 Creation time :  0.187678098679
Approach 1 Total time :  0.286989927292
Approach 2 Total time :  10.208632946
```

So my question is this is there a better way of doing this? I find forming sparse matrix to be an overkill as it takes more than half of the time. Are there any better alternatives? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try Sparse-sum : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sum.html?

Comment: *Gasp! A whole 433ms to run through only ten billion items!* --- You might want to write your own subroutines (in a lower-level language?) for something like this.

Comment: @Divakar I tried it. Please see the edit. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to test alternatives if you gave a full working example.  I started to set things up, but gave up after the dimensions got too confusing.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry for not being clear. I have added working example. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That sparse `X` slicing is actually done with a matrix product.  I describe that process in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int.  So your iteration is replacing one `S.dot` with `s` smaller ones.  And the sparse `sum` is also a matrix product.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. Clearly this means approach2 can not be improved over approach 1. But does this mean that there is no better alternative as well? Because as I said its taking more than half of the time to just create S from map_fn. Can we use map_fn directly somehow? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Starting approach**

Adapting [`sparse solution from this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457039/3293881) -

```
def sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod1(X, rows):   
    nrows = rows.max()+1
    ncols = X.shape[1]
    nelem = nrows * ncols

    a,b = X.nonzero()
    ids = rows[a] + b*nrows
    sums = np.bincount(ids, X[a,b].A1, minlength=nelem)
    out = sums.reshape(ncols,-1).T
    return out
```

**Benchmarking**

Original approach #1 -

```
def app1(X, map_fn):
    col = scipy.arange(n)
    val = np.ones(n)
    S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix( (val, (map_fn, col)), shape = (s,n))
    SX = S.dot(X)
    return SX
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [209]: # Inputs setup
     ...: s=10000
     ...: n=1000000
     ...: d=1000
     ...: density=1.0/500
     ...: 
     ...: X=scipy.sparse.rand(n,d,density=density,format="csr")
     ...: map_fn=np.random.randint(0, s, n)
     ...: 

In [210]: out1 = app1(X, map_fn)
     ...: out2 = sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod1(X, map_fn)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1.toarray(), out2)
     ...: 
True

In [211]: %timeit app1(X, map_fn)
1 loop, best of 3: 517 ms per loop

In [212]: %timeit sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod1(X, map_fn)
10 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop
```

To be fair, we should time the final dense array version from `app1` -

```
In [214]: %timeit app1(X, map_fn).toarray()
1 loop, best of 3: 584 ms per loop
```

---

**Porting to Numba**

We could translate the binned counting step to numba, which might be beneficial for denser input matrices. One of the ways to do so would be -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def bincount_mod2(out, rows, r, C, V):
    N = len(V)
    for i in range(N):
        out[rows[r[i]], C[i]] += V[i]
    return out

def sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod2(X, rows):
    nrows = rows.max()+1
    ncols = X.shape[1]
    r,C = X.nonzero()

    V = X[r,C].A1
    out = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
    return bincount_mod2(out, rows, r, C, V)
```

Timings -

```
In [373]: # Inputs setup
     ...: s=10000
     ...: n=1000000
     ...: d=1000
     ...: density=1.0/100 # Denser now!
     ...: 
     ...: X=scipy.sparse.rand(n,d,density=density,format="csr")
     ...: map_fn=np.random.randint(0, s, n)
     ...: 

In [374]: %timeit app1(X, map_fn)
1 loop, best of 3: 787 ms per loop

In [375]: %timeit sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod1(X, map_fn)
1 loop, best of 3: 906 ms per loop

In [376]: %timeit sparse_matrix_mult_sparseX_mod2(X, map_fn)
1 loop, best of 3: 705 ms per loop
```

With the dense output from `app1` -

```
In [379]: %timeit app1(X, map_fn).toarray()
1 loop, best of 3: 910 ms per loop
```

Comment: @Thank you for introducing me to numba.